# Print Label in two columns - Qweb report OdooV10

Tags: odoo-10, qweb

I'm trying to create a Qweb report into Odoo Version 10, My requirement is to Print the for-each values in two columns in row,

```
<t t-call="report.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
           <!-- Here i need to print the doc data in two columns , then proceed to next row -->
             </t>
 </t>
```

Please anybody help me to print the data in two columns and then proceed to row

Comment: cant understand your requirement

Answer (score 1):

## Try This

### In your report template, add this code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p t-field="enter your name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" >
        <p t-field="enter your name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```